# how would you make an IE5 only website that uses HTC work in a modern web browser?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've got a client that has used [this lovely feature of IE 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018(v=vs.85).aspx) to build a website. It is mission critical and there is a very long project in progress to replace it.

However in the meantime we are stuck using IE5!

Is there a polyfill available to make this work?
What other options do you think there are?

Note that we want this to work on non windows platforms so just embedding IE5 in chrome is not going to cut it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, "You don't."

HTCs (or HTML Components) were originally [introduced in IE5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532146(v=vs.85).aspx), but were declared deprecated with the release of IE7 (2006) and obsolete (unsupported) [as of IE10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801216(v%3dvs.85)) (2012).

It was possible to use them up through IE9, provided you set your pages to use [IE5Quirks mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v%3dvs.85)); however, this feature was only implemented in Internet Explorer.  No other browser, including Microsoft Edge, supported document modes.<sup>[1]</sup>

Now that Internet Explorer is no [longer supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support), I'm afraid this means there is no way, supported or not, to enable Chrome, Firefox, Brave, or any other modern browser to support HTCs on Windows....let alone macOS or Linux.

Depending on what your HTCs specifically implemented, you may be able to use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [NWjs](https://nwjs.io/) (or related technologies) to re-implement your solution using modern technologies.  Since these are based on Chromium, the final solution works on many platforms, not just Windows.<sup>[2]</sup>

It means rebuilding the solution from scratch, but you have a much broader, more modern palette to work with, so it may not be as difficult as [it sounds](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps).

Sorry...

[1] - OK, Chrome did support [document modes](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)....briefly.  The point is that it no longer does and your best bet is to rewrite for HTML5 and other modern design techniques.

[2] - Yes, I know most browsers supported W3C [quirks mode](http://jkorpela.fi/quirks-mode.html) at one point, but that doesn't a) give you HTC support in a browser that never supported the feature or b) enable HTC support on non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! While I don't endorse the use of ancient technology there are times when you've just got to keep it running. We are in a multi year project to replace this system - in the meantime I'd like to have a way of at least migrating off IE5!

Comment: You have a way: study the current implementation, identify the features that are needed, and then re-implement them using modern, standards-based technologies.

I can't be more specific, partly because you haven't been more specific.  What did you do in the HTC that you haven't figured out how to do using more modern techniques?

In a sense, it's like migrating from one platform to another.  No one expects Android or iOS to implement Win32 features.  Instead, you catalog the things you need and figure out how to execute them using the new set of tools.

Comment: It is more a question of scale, of course there is nothing that can't be re implemented but that has a cost. There are thousands of lines of this stuff. It is not going to be upgraded to modern code that is just out of the question. Like I said we are replacing the system but that is a long project so if there was a way of polyfilling this then I'd be all over it. As it stands the way htc are applied using the behavior css property it looks like it is not possible due to the fact invalid css properties aren't applied. Otherwise a polyfill looks to be pretty easy to implement.